# Accessing operator inside struct itself

Tags: c++, struct, operators

I'm trying to access an operator inside the struct itself, is this possible?

```
struct st{
    float vd;
    float val(){
      return this[3]; //this dont work, is there a some way?
    }
    float operator[](size_t idx){
        return  vd*idx;
    }
};
```

Comment: The reason why `this[3]` doesn't work is because this is a pointer, so the operator is not called, but the code works as with all pointers (`this + 3`) which returns a pointer to an imaginary 'st struct at the distance of 3 'st'-s to this one.  The returned 'st' can't be converted to a float.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the object not the object itself.  If you want to call a member function you can call the function directly

```
float val(){
  return operator[](3);
}
```

or you can dereference `this` and call `[]` on the actual object.

```
float val(){
  return (*this)[3];
}
```

Since `this` is a pointer `return this[3];` translated to `return (this + 3);` which means give me the object that resides address of `this + sizeof(st)*3` which is an invalid object since `this` is not an array.  This is UB and will also cause a compiler error as the type of `this[3]` is a `st` and your function is supposed to return a `float`.